# how to add pagination to the organize series plugin

Tags: posts, pagination

I'm thinking of using the organize series plugin for posts featuring learning videos. As they are step1, step2 etc I'd rather use pagination instead of the next/previous links. Does anyone know how I'd do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Organize Series](http://organizeseries.com) includes built in navigation.  You can modify the output of the navigation area via the series options page.